# Problemas com certificado a utilizar GIT em https

Tags: git, certificado-digital

Os repositórios GIT a que estou a aceder passaram a estar disponíveis apenas em HTTPS. No entanto quando tento aceder ao repositório, obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://<endereço>/scm/ec/repo.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate

Completed with errors, see above.
```

Comment: Já encontrei a solução. Basta desactivar a validação de certificados no cliente GIT, neste caso no SourceTree.

Answer (score 2):

Já encontrei a solução. Basta desactivar a validação de certificados no cliente GIT, neste caso no SourceTree